# Windows explorer is using constantly >30% CPU

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cpu-usage

Windows version 1903, but i am sure it was like this also on 1804
No Virus, have ESET running and did a check
sfc /now does not show any errors

Windows explorer will use constantly around 30-50% CPU if i have "Show all Folders" enabled.
If i disable this then CPU is <1%

What is the problem and is it possible to get this option to work without the high cpu usage ?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. Most likely you have a virus, just not detected by ESET.

Comment: Without more info this will be impossible to assist with

Comment: Maybe grab an ETL trace by running: `wpr -start GeneralProfile -start CPU` reproduce the issue and then run `wpr -stop %temp%\cpu.etl` If you can provide a link to the ETL file that would be good.